# Vue TransitionGroup not working properly because of css transition

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vuejs-transition-group

After debugging for several hours I concluded that Vue  does not work well with the CSS transition property.

The transition group: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group

```
<TransitionGroup name="store" tag="div">
  <button v-for="item in store.items" :key="item">{{ item.name}}</button>
</TransitionGroup>
```

Vue3 transition classes: [css-based-transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions)

```
.store-move,
.store-enter-active,
.store-leave-active {
  transition:
    opacity 500ms ease,
    transform 500ms ease; // reference 1
}

.store-enter-from,
.store-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(2rem);
}

.store-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Relevant styles on the buttons (using [scss](https://sass-lang.com/)):

```
button {
  display: block;
  transition: transform 150ms ease; // reference 2

  &:hover {
   transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  &:active {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

**Option A:**
The transition group does not work at all unless you put `!important` on the vue transition class (reference 1).
**Option B:**
Comment out the transition on the button selector (reference 2).

In both scenarios the transition group does not work as expected because of the shared transform property on the transition.

**Option C:**
When commenting out everything below `reference 1` aswell, the transition group works perfectly.

I have not yet found any workaround to this problem.